# How does JMockIt work under the hood with multiple expectations?

Tags: java, mocking, jmockit

For example:

```
class JMockItTest {
    @Injectable Foo foo;
    @Test void test() {
        new Expectations() {{
            foo.nonVoidMethod();
            result = "a";
            result = "b";
            result = "c";
        }};
        assertEquals("a", foo.nonVoidMethod());
        assertEquals("b", foo.nonVoidMethod());
        assertEquals("c", foo.nonVoidMethod());
    }
}
```

This example will tell JMockIt to return `"a"` then `"b"` then `"c"` for each of the 3 invocations of `nonVoidMethod()`... but how does this work?  It's not possible to override operators like `=` in Java, so how does simply assigning `result = x` multiple times tell JMockIt what to return?